# Grails page ends up as 404 on production server

Tags: spring, grails

I have used `compile ':spring-security-core:2.0-RC2'` in my application. Now when the user logins successfully, he/she will get redirected to another page.

Part of my Config.groovy file is as follows:

```
// Added by the Spring Security Core plugin:
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'com.app.auth.User'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'com.app.auth.UserRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'com.app.auth.Role'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl ="/Person/createMan"
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
```

Upon user successfully logins the user gets redirected as shown in the above config file. `"/Person/createMan"`. However when the user gets redirected the page end up being a 404.

```
123.231.15.97 - - [03/Aug/2014:12:43:35 +0200] "GET /MyProjec/Person/createMan HTTP/1.1" 404 1091
```

Note: `Person` is located in `myprojec` package.

Comment: `Note: Person is located in myprojec package.` what does it mean? according to your URL, you deploy your app as `MyProject.war`. So, it doesn't have anything to do with a package

Comment: Anyway, i end up getting 404 for every view in the `myprojec` package. All the views in   `com.app.auth.User` gets displayed.

Comment: can you open `/Person/createMan` directly?

Comment: @injecteer No i am not able to do so.

Comment: so, it's not a problem of `spring-security`

Comment: Oh. Any clue to sort this issue ?

Comment: if you don't have any custom url-mapping, try `/person/createMan`

Comment: Could it be that you develop on a windows machine and there is a problem with upper/lower case in your projects structure?

Comment: i developed using a MAC. and trying to deploy on a Ubuntu server.

Comment: @Illep: Is the value of 'grails.serverUrl' (in Config.groovy) correct for the production environment ?

Comment: Yes. Its `http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8084/MyProject`

Comment: Is this a mispel? "GET /MyProjec/Person/createMan HTTP/1.1" you have "MyProjec" instead of "MyProject"

Comment: It;s misspelt in the question. But i have it correct in the project. I just typed WAR in the grails prompt to produce the WAR file. Is it how you guys did it too. Or did you type `prod war` to generate the WAR file for production ?

Comment: 'war' is enough, prod is default. But again, you probably copied this log entry: "123.231.15.97 - - [03/Aug/2014:12:43:35 +0200] "GET /MyProjec/Person/createMan HTTP/1.1" 404 1091" and there you have a MyProjec isntead of MyProject